# Render Html with Svelte tag from string

Tags: svelte, svelte-component

I would like to generate html components (buttons) in my script in js that have svelte tag like on:click :

```
<button class="inline-flex items-center border-t-2 border-transparent px-4 pt-4 text-sm font-medium text-gray-500 hover:border-gray-300 hover:text-gray-700"
        aria-current="page"
        on:click={() => {
            managePages(10);
        }}
    >
        10
</button>
```

But when I display it with `{@html button}` it doesn't matter of the on:click tag...

That's my code of html generation with svelte tag in js :

```js
for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
  if (i == $trialsPage) {
    html += `<button
            class="inline-flex cursor-pointer items-center border-t-2 border-mpe-color1 px-4 pt-4 text-sm font-medium text-mpe-color1"
            aria-current="page"
            on:click="{() => {
                managePages(${i});
            }}"
        >
            ${i}
        </button>`;
  } else {
    html += `<button
            class="inline-flex items-center border-t-2 border-transparent px-4 pt-4 text-sm font-medium text-gray-500 hover:border-gray-300 hover:text-gray-700"
            aria-current="page"
            on:click="{() => {
                managePages(${i});
            }}"
        >
        ${i}
        </button>`;
  }
}
```

How can I get Svelte to take the tag into account from the string ?

Comment: You should *not* generate HTML in JS, the whole point of tools like Svelte is to avoid that. Please learn about the various directives like `{#if}` and `{#each}`.

Answer (score -1):

```
{#if nbPages > 0 && nbPages <= 5}
    <div class="my-5 flex items-center justify-between border-t border-gray-200 px-4 sm:px-0">
        <div class="-mt-px flex w-0 flex-1">
            <button
                class="inline-flex items-center border-t-2 border-transparent pt-4 pr-1 text-sm font-medium text-gray-500 hover:border-mpe-color1 hover:text-mpe-color1"
            >
                <Icon src="{ArrowCircleLeft}" theme="outline" size="50px" class="mr-3 h-5 w-5" />
                Previous
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="hidden md:-mt-px md:flex">
            {#each Array(nbPages) as row, i}
                {#if i + 1 == $trialsPage}
                    <button
                        class="inline-flex cursor-pointer items-center border-t-2 border-mpe-color1 px-4 pt-4 text-sm font-medium text-mpe-color1"
                        aria-current="page"
                        on:click="{() => {
                            managePages(i + 1);
                        }}"
                    >
                        {i + 1}
                    </button>
                {:else}
                    <button
                        class="inline-flex items-center border-t-2 border-transparent px-4 pt-4 text-sm font-medium text-gray-500 hover:border-gray-300 hover:text-gray-700"
                        aria-current="page"
                        on:click="{() => {
                            managePages(i + 1);
                        }}"
                    >
                        {i + 1}
                    </button>
                {/if}
            {/each}
        </div>
        <div class="-mt-px flex w-0 flex-1 justify-end">
            <button
                class="inline-flex items-center border-t-2 border-transparent pt-4 pl-1 text-sm font-medium text-gray-500 hover:border-mpe-color1 hover:text-mpe-color1"
            >
                Next
                <Icon src="{ArrowCircleRight}" theme="outline" size="50px" class="ml-3 h-5 w-5" />
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
{:else if nbPages > 0 && nbPages > 5}
    <div class="my-5 flex items-center justify-between border-t border-gray-200 px-4 sm:px-0">
        <div class="-mt-px flex w-0 flex-1">
            <button
                class="inline-flex items-center border-t-2 border-transparent pt-4 pr-1 text-sm font-medium text-gray-500 hover:border-mpe-color1 hover:text-mpe-color1"
            >
                <Icon src="{ArrowCircleLeft}" theme="outline" size="50px" class="mr-3 h-5 w-5" />
                Previous
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="hidden md:-mt-px md:flex">
            {#each Array(3) as row, i}
                {#if i + 1 == $trialsPage}
                    <button
                        class="inline-flex cursor-pointer items-center border-t-2 border-mpe-color1 px-4 pt-4 text-sm font-medium text-mpe-color1"
                        aria-current="page"
                        on:click="{() => {
                            managePages(i + 1);
                        }}"
                    >
                        {i + 1}
                    </button>
                {:else}
                    <button
                        class="inline-flex items-center border-t-2 border-transparent px-4 pt-4 text-sm font-medium text-gray-500 hover:border-gray-300 hover:text-gray-700"
                        aria-current="page"
                        on:click="{() => {
                            managePages(i + 1);
                        }}"
                    >
                        {i + 1}
                    </button>
                {/if}
            {/each}
            <span class="inline-flex items-center border-t-2 border-transparent px-4 pt-4 text-sm font-medium text-gray-500">...</span>
            <button
                class="inline-flex items-center border-t-2 border-transparent px-4 pt-4 text-sm font-medium text-gray-500 hover:border-gray-300 hover:text-gray-700"
                aria-current="page"
                on:click="{() => {
                    managePages(nbPages - 2);
                }}"
            >
                {nbPages - 2}
            </button>
            <button
                class="inline-flex items-center border-t-2 border-transparent px-4 pt-4 text-sm font-medium text-gray-500 hover:border-gray-300 hover:text-gray-700"
                aria-current="page"
                on:click="{() => {
                    managePages(nbPages - 1);
                }}"
            >
                {nbPages - 1}
            </button>
            <button
                class="inline-flex items-center border-t-2 border-transparent px-4 pt-4 text-sm font-medium text-gray-500 hover:border-gray-300 hover:text-gray-700"
                aria-current="page"
                on:click="{() => {
                    managePages(nbPages);
                }}"
            >
                {nbPages}
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="-mt-px flex w-0 flex-1 justify-end">
            <button
                class="inline-flex items-center border-t-2 border-transparent pt-4 pl-1 text-sm font-medium text-gray-500 hover:border-mpe-color1 hover:text-mpe-color1"
            >
                Next
                <Icon src="{ArrowCircleRight}" theme="outline" size="50px" class="ml-3 h-5 w-5" />
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
{/if}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).